# Get the current document viewport in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, envdte, vspackage, vs-extensibility

I am writing a *VSPackage*. I need to get the text from the current document in the *Visual Studio*, edit the text and write it back to the current open document.

When I do this, the current viewport of the document jumps back to the top of the document:

**Example** Let's say you're working on a document which contains 2000 lines of code, and currently in *Visual Studio* code editor you see the line numbers 500 to 550. And the cursor is some where at line 700.

After processing the document text, I want the user to see the same line numbers in the code editor and also I want the cursor to stay where it was.

I found some solutions for moving the cursor, however, still couldn't find how to `Get` and `Set` the current view port on the active document.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iviewscroller(v=vs.120).aspx

Use IViewScroller.  It has methods keep a desired span in view, which is most likely what you want,  or to scroll by a specified number of lines.  Just get its instance with the ViewScroller property of the text view object.